# Removing suspect MITM certificate while only knowing Date Issued?

Tags: certificates, man-in-the-middle, threat-mitigation

A Blue Coat type of certificate was added to my personal PC to access a business network which I could trust at the time, but I don't trust the certificate issuer (Blue Coat) in general and don't necessarily trust that network all the time. Problem is, I'm not sure what the certificate was called and don't have access to the network now - this was done with some haste and on a PC that is not security critical. Still, I'd like to learn how to correct this.

I do know the date it would have been first stored, but in Windows 10 Internet Properties > Content > Certificates the only date property is the Expiration Date. **Is there a way to view certificates by Date Issued or Stored on my end?** That would let me ID the cert in question and remove that.

Otherwise, can I simply reset all my certificates somehow and 'start with a clean slate'? Is the correct way to do that "Windows 10 Internet Properties > Content > Clear SSL state"? I realize I'll get scary warnings at all new HTTPS requests at that point, but I understand that would give me the opportunity to selectively accept certificates and verify when in doubt.